# How to insert C# YouTube API 'upload' code into a Azure blob trigger function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-api, youtube-api, azure-functions

I am trying to use the YouTube API "upload" sample code ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert ) and place it in an Azure function. For example, if there is a new video in my blob container, the azure function should get triggered, and upload the video to my YouTube channel(for this I am using the YouTube API). I am wondering, how can I take the "upload" code and put it in an azure function? This how I have done it, but I am unsure if this function is structured/setup right or does it need to be modified? Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using System.Reflection;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.Threading;

namespace UploadVideoBlob
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("video/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]Stream myBlob, string name, ILogger log)
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            using(var stream = new FileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(context.FunctionDirectory, "client_secrets.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None
                );
            }

            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "Default Video Title";
            video.Snippet.Description = "Default Video Description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "22";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";
            var VideoInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", myBlob, "video/*");
            await VideoInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Local Setting.Json file:

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=uploadvideotoyoutube;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```

client_secrets.json

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "147300761218-dl0rhktkoj8arh0ebu5pu56es06hje5p.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "mytestproj",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"]
  }
}
```

Comment: so whats your question? Is this working? or do you get an error?

Comment: It is not working, I am wondering if I had placed in the  youtube API code correctly?

Comment: I'm wondering that it even compiles. You method should be async: `public static async Task Run(...)`

Comment: Yes, I have made that change. My main question is, did I structure the azure function correctly with the youtube code? How would you have structured it?

Comment: you could probably reuse some parts over multiple function calls, such as your `youtubeService` but general the structure looks ok. But I'm also not familiar with the specifics of the youtube API

Comment: And: a) please add error messages etc which show that "it is not working". and b) amend your code above if you have made changes in the meantime

Comment: It seems them no one has been able to help on this question yet. I will add more details and modify it

Comment: @Bryan Lewis , do you mind checking to see?

Comment: I still dont see an error message - or a better description of "is not working

Comment: @silent your are missing the point. The code currently fine, just does't do anything.

Comment: you keep saying "it is not working" or "doesnt do anything". That is not very specific. Is the code running fine (do you have logging in there to prove it?) but not uploading to youtube or what is happening?

Comment: @silent thanks for your help.